# JQuery styling does not get applied

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use JQuery to style my HTML page but it does not work.

Is my JQuery correct?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").css("color", "red");
    });
</script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center jumbotron">
    <h1 id="heading1">Protector of the Environment</h1>
    <h3 id="heading2">Wangari Maathai</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include jquery library? Are you seeing any errors in your console>

Comment: More questions: Do heading1 and heading2 have separate color-styles? Do you have any error in your browser console?

Comment: You're leaving out details because the code you posted [demonstrably works](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k1kd3no1/)

Comment: It seems that code work fine, Can you open the Console and lookout for errors.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center jumbotron">
    <h1 id="heading1">Protector of the Environment</h1>
    <h3 id="heading2">Wangari Maathai</h3>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").css("color", "red");
    });
</script> // working absolutely fine

Comment: working good as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I only add jquery library and it works well. check below snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").css("color", "red");
    });
</script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center jumbotron">
    <h1 id="heading1">Protector of the Environment</h1>
    <h3 id="heading2">Wangari Maathai</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this type of issue may generate due to CSS applied to h1 and h3 which cannot override by the parent div so try to apply CSS to h1 and h3 also

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div, div h1, div h3 ").css("color", "red");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid text-center jumbotron">
    <h1 id="heading1">Protector of the Environment</h1>
    <h3 id="heading2">Wangari Maathai</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").css("color", "red");
    });
</script>


<div class="container-fluid text-center jumbotron">
    <h1 id="heading1">Protector of the Environment</h1>
    <h3 id="heading2">Wangari Maathai</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `jquery` library is required to be explicitly added via `script` tag. Your code will start to work after you add the library.

The `jquery` library can be added by using a CDN (content delivery network)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or you can use a local jquery file if you have it.

```
<script src="myProject/JavaScripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the jquery library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply css with classname.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.text-center").css("color", "red");
    });
</script>
```